# Existe árvore binária no .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, árvore-binária

Não sei se está escondido em algum lugar e não vi uma estrutura de árvore binária no .NET.

Procurei na documentação de toda `Collection`, incluindo os subníveis e nada. Não tem mesmo? Por que não teria algo tão importante?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Árvore binária costuma ter problemas com localidade de referência, então evita-se o uso. O .NET Framework e Core tenta fornecer as estruturas mais úteis apenas e deixar para cada um prover as demais, principalmente se considerar que existem diversas formas de implementar uma árvore binária, o .NET não poderia entregar todas necessárias.

Na verdade até existe árvore binária no .NET, mas isso é considerado detalhe de implementação de estruturas que garantem certo compromisso, nada garante que será uma árvore binária. É melhor dar soluções do que estruturas específicas. Veja [`SortedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0). Também existe o [`SortedList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

Existem algumas implementações prontas, talvez as mais conhecidas sejam [`PowerCollections`](https://www.wintellect.com/power-collections-library/) (espero que eles migrem para o GitHub, [há quem colocou](https://github.com/timdetering/Wintellect.PowerCollections)) e a [C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5). Talvez encontre alguma que seja útil para sua necessidade lá. Senão tem que procurar por outras ou fazer sua própria implementação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).